# What is the default root password for mariadb in Arch Linux?

Tags: arch-linux, mariadb

I install `mariadb` in arch-linux. but I haven't got access to MySQL.
I try this:

```
 mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

I see very similar question, and test all of answers but I can't resolve it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should have been asked for the password during installation.

In case you do not remember your password, you can always [reset your password](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/MariaDB#Reset_the_root_password).

Answer (score 3):

[The wiki says](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/MariaDB#Configuration) you should be able to log in with an empty password for root like so:

```bsh
$ mysql -u root -p
```

However, you may still get an error when you use an empty password:

```
ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
```

You also need to be the system root user in order to log in via this account. You can use sudo to accomplish this:

```bsh
$ sudo mysql -u root -p
```

This should let you log in as root.

Answer (score 0):

Mariadb/Mysql

Reset password using this link.
https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=51981

```
sudo rm -r /var/lib/mysql
sudo pacman -Rn mysql
sudo pacman -S mysql
sudo /usr/bin/mysql_install_db
sudo /usr/bin/mysql_secure_installation
```

you can run all the commands, running last command again worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

first you must to start the service (/etc/init.d/mysqld start). if the installation didn't ask you the password simply press Enter.

sudo mysql -u root -p

Answer (score -2):

first you must to start the service (/etc/init.d/mysqld start). if the installation didn't ask you the password simply press Enter.

Comment: Arch Linux uses systemd. There is no `/etc/init.d`.